# Global Javascript variables in Webkit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit, global-variables

I have Chrome 7.0 and am trying to access fields of a global object.  The code is working perfectly in Firefox and IE, but Chrome's debugger isn't helping me get anywhere.  I tried Safari and it's also having trouble.

I can get the value of timer, but when I access status through the console I get `"[object Object]"`.  `status.completedJobs` returns `undefined` even after `status = $.parseJSON(msg.d);` (json string is valid).

I'm not sure what to do after this. Calling `$.parseJSON(msg.d);` from console works and I'm able to view the object's fields with the debugger.  How do I get the status Object properly assigned and globally accessible?

Here's my code:

```
//Object that holds result of AJAX request
var status = new Object();
//Refresh timer variables
var timer;
var timer_is_on = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    update();
    doTimer();
});

/**
 * Performs the AJAX request and updates the page
 */
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/getStatus",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg) {
                try {
                    status = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                updateProgressBar();
            }
        }
    });
}

function updateProgressBar() {
    var percent = Math.round(status.completedJobs / status.numJobs * 100);
    $('#progressPercentage').text(percent + '%');
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value: percent
    });
}

/**
 * Used to initialize the timer.
 */
function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        timer_is_on = 1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

/**
 * Executed on every time interval.
 */
function timedCount() {
    update();
    timer = setTimeout("timedCount()", 3000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.dir()`?

Comment: Are you very sure about `msg.d`? And what data do you get back?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys.

`console.dir()` results in `undefined`.

msg.d's response is:
`{"d":"{\"numJobs\":269389,\"completedJobs\":102423,\"running\":true}"}`

Comment: what do you mean by 'access status through the console' in Chrome?    I am also in Chrome 7, and when I do a console.log(varName) it gives me the option to expand the object for browsing. Furthermore, I can type varName directly into the console and hit enter to get the same (not to mention auto-complete on the variable name to show it sees it)  The only time I see [object Object] notation is when using alerts()

Comment: You can browse through the DOM using the debugger, that's where I saw the [object Object]. Once you have the console open, you can type the varname and it'll show you the contents without having to do an explicit console.log in the code.  You can also call functions in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using another name than **status**, there is a predefined member of **window**(window is the global object in browser-based JS) called "status".  It also would be good if you assign the global variable to the window-object to avoid conflicts if there exists a variable in the current (not global) scope with the same name:

```
window['statusVar'] = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
```

Comment: Works perfectly across all!  Thanks for the help, I'm somewhat of a javascript noob.

Comment: nice find Dr.Molle.  Pulling up the console in Chrome and typing in 'status' just here on StackOverflow and also on Google I can see it is defined